# Is there any risk of someone knowing my license key of Windows 8?

Tags: windows-8, security

I am in the process of purchasing Windows 8 and then upgrading right away to 8.1 for free via the store. I have found a eBay seller that sends you a licence key and a download. However, is there any risk of hacking/them "revoking" my licence remotely?

**Note: I will take precautionary actions to verify non-hacked and genuine key/download (I will download *directly* from MS's site (going there directly through the navigation bar). Also I have heard about a tool that you can use to verify authenticity of a key.** The seller guarantees a key is valid and will replace it if not, so it's not a problem with eBay Buyer Protection. I am wondering if just knowing the key alone is dangerous.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a good rule of thumb, **never** buy software license keys off of eBay. Regardless of what the seller guarantees, they are very often illegitimate and get revoked. And if your Win 8 key is revoked, your Win 8.1 install is no good.

There's a reason they're so much cheaper on eBay. You get what you pay for. There are many stories on the Internet just like [this one](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/3ec5bec4-570c-4529-8176-6e8930766d5f/buying-a-windows-7-ultimate-key-off-ebay?forum=w7itproinstall).

I'm all about a good deal, but I never recommend buying keys for any software off eBay unless it's boxed software, sealed and certified.

Comment: See the thread to which I linked. A common tactic here is to use MSDN or TechNet keys, which are valid and will verify, but are only for the use of the subscriber who bought them, and will become invalid for everyone soon when MS does away with TechNet subs.

Comment: In addition, a key can be revoked by MS anytime they feel it is invalid. It's in the EULA. Your system will eventually "call home" and deliver its installation ID, and if the key is invalid, it can be revoked.

Comment: You were right. Scam. Sent them a quick message and next day account deleted. However, another one popped up on search. Same exact thing down to the feedback and title. Haven't had time to report to eBay or Microsoft yet tho will keep watching. I ended up finding it at a reputable dealer for a little more. Will buy there. Learned my lesson good thing I didn't buy it!!!

Comment: Glad to see you got it sorted and dodged a bullet.