# Have XP upgrading to Windows 8 and then to 8.1: Should I run both the Windows 8 and 8.1 upgrade assistant to check for compatibility? Will this work?

Tags: windows, windows-xp, windows-8, upgrade, windows-8-upgrade

I found Windows 8 Pro for 1/3 the price of 8.1 Core, and with the free upgrade, I am going this route to get Windows 8.1 Pro cheaper than 8.1 Core. I'm currently working out the issues with security and the key (Question: [Is there any risk of someone knowing my license key of Windows 8?](https://superuser.com/questions/671774/is-there-any-risk-of-someone-knowing-my-license-key-of-windows-8)).

How should I manage to check if my PC is compatible. I've seen the horror stories online about computers not compatible with 8.1 but with 8 only. I can run the 8 upgrade assistant and then what to determine that it is compatible for both?

Comment: you should post your hardware specs.

Comment: @magicandre1981 Sorry just saw this. It's an Acer Aspire One ZG5. On my phone can't look it up easily now.

Comment: upgrading from 8 to 8.1 fill fail because the display is not meting the requirements to run the new apps. You need to get the 8.1 ISO and install it this way. Run the 8.1 upgrade assistant and looks what it tells you.

Comment: @magicandre1981 I have an external monitor, will this qualify? I always knew the problem about apps... on MS's support page it lists it under "required for some features" and my monitor will work and I always use it.

Comment: this can work. I don't have such an old netbook so I can't test this

Comment: @magicandre1981 http://www.askvg.com/how-to-force-enable-windows-8-snap-feature-in-low-screen-resolutions/ Yay a fix!